# Getting "already an existing command or alias" when trying to make a help command in a separate cog

Tags: python, discord

When I made my bot I stored everything in my main file, but once I learned more and more I used cogs to store my commands.

After adding all of them to cogs I decided to make my own help command (one is using was prebuilt somehow). But even after following a tutorial this is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 946, in _load_from_module_spec
    await setup(self)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/Discord Mortibi/New/cogs/help.py", line 25, in setup
    await client.add_cog(HelpCommand(client))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 782, in add_cog
    cog = await cog._inject(self, override=override, guild=guild, guilds=guilds)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/cog.py", line 687, in _inject
    raise e
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/cog.py", line 678, in _inject
    bot.add_command(command)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 245, in add_command
    super().add_command(command)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1348, in add_command
    raise CommandRegistrationError(command.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 60, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<string>", line 57, in main
  File "<string>", line 53, in load
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1012, in load_extension
    await self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 951, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.help' raised an error: CommandRegistrationError: The command help is already an existing command or alias.
[Program finished]
```

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os

class HelpCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("help.py is loaded")

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        help_embed = discord.Embed(title="Placeholder", description="All Commands ph", color=discord.Color.purple())
        help_embed.set_author(name="Ph hold")
        help_embed.add_field(name="Clear", value="Deletes message", inline=False)
        help_embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by <@{ctx.author}>.", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        await ctx.send(embed=help_embed)

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(HelpCommand(client))
```

Comment: Why are you using a whole cog for a singular command?

Comment: was i not supposed to?

Comment: Cogs are groups of commands, just like a category of commands, for example "Fun"

Comment: Fun fact : I actually made a category called that
okay but now i get it
but there's is nothing really wrong about what i am using cogs for
the real error is why cant i replace the prebuilt help file

Comment: Try renaming the command to something like _help, and add `name="help"` to commands.command()